# Using dynamic DB Schema name when defining procedure in esql

Tags: ibm-app-connect

I'm using AppConnect v12 and I'm trying to write a DB stored procedure from esql using the below piece of code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer_SP (
    IN custNo INT,
    INOUT responseCode CHAR)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE DATABASE
EXTERNAL NAME "DBSchemaDev.SPName";
```

where the DBSchema varies from environment to another, so I need it to be variable according to the environment and I will get its value from config. file
For example, for test environment, it is called DBSchemaTest and so on..
I tried the below

```
DECLARE DBSchema CHARACTER 'DBSchemaDev';
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer_SP (
    IN custNo INT,
    INOUT responseCode CHAR)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE DATABASE
EXTERNAL NAME DBSchema || ".SPName";
```

but it is not working,
I tried also below

```
DECLARE DBSchema CHARACTER 'DBSchemaDev';
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer_SP (
    IN custNo INT,
    INOUT responseCode CHAR)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE DATABASE
EXTERNAL NAME "{DBSchema}.SPName";
```

but it is not working as well,
so I was wondering if there is possibility to use variables in the EXTERNAL NAME field

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. I used to call the stored procedure as below

```
DECLARE DBSchema CHARACTER 'esb'; --where esb is retrieved from config. file
CALL getCustomer_SP(custNo, responseCode) IN Database.{DBSchema};
```

where I removed the schema name from the stored procedure definition as below

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer_SP (
    IN custNo INT,
    INOUT responseCode CHAR)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE DATABASE
EXTERNAL NAME "SPName";
```